# Searching Java array, stops after first instance

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, arraylist

Quick question all,

I'm currently working on a program, and I'm trying to input a number into a GUI and have the program search an array to find that number then output the next number in that array. I was able to complete this, however the for loop only works for the first set of numbers. I'm able to input 7623, and it populates 2000
.00, so I know I'm on the right track. I might have an issue with my for loop, but have been scratching my head. Thanks for all of your help.

```
private double[][] arrayValues = {
        {7623, 2000.00},
        {7623, 1200.00},
        {8729, 1000.00},
        {8729, 1700.00},
        {7321, 4500.00},
        {3242, 4612.00},
        {3242, 100.00},
        {9823, 234.00},
        {9823, 2345.00},
        {2341, 12373.12},
        {2341, 5421.12},
        {8321, 2314.00},
        {8321, 56233.00}
    };

        private void requestBalanceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        actnum = Double.parseDouble(accountNumber.getText());
        int match = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) {
            double accountNo = arrayValues[i][0];

            initialBalance.setText(", ");

            if (accountNo == actnum) {

                balance = arrayValues[i][1];
                accountIndex = i;
                initialBalance.setText(Double.toString(balance));
                initialBalance.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                match = 1;
            }

            if (match != 1) {

                initialBalance.setText(Double.toString(0));
                initialBalance.setText("Acct # does not exist. Please try again.");
                initialBalance.setForeground(Color.RED);
```

/////////////////////NEW CODE/////////////

So, this instance of code now lets me search for different numbers within the array, however I had to take out the initialBalance.setText(" "); to get it to work. When I search for 7623, it's now outputting 1200.00 instead of 2000.00, and it does this for every #, skipping the first instance of the number. I believe it has something to do with the .setText that I deleted??

```
        private void requestBalanceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        actnum = Double.parseDouble(accountNumber.getText());
        int match = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayValues.length; i++) {
            double accountNo = arrayValues[i][0];



            if (accountNo == actnum) {

                balance = arrayValues[i][1];
                accountIndex = i;
                initialBalance.setText(Double.toString(balance));
                initialBalance.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                match = 1;
            }
        }
            if (match != 1) {

                initialBalance.setText(Double.toString(0));
                initialBalance.setText("Acct # does not exist. Please try again.");
                initialBalance.setForeground(Color.RED);

            }
```

Comment: What is your desired output when you enter 7623? Or some other value for which you are getting undesired results?

Comment: 2000.00 is my desired output, however 2000.0 will work as well

Comment: So, when I input "8729" its not recognizing it, and goes straight to the "if" loop for the match != 1. Bypassing the if accoungNo==actnum. I want to say it has something to do with the array containing int/doubles? Let me know your thoughts and thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide the full implementation of the method requestBalanceActionPerformed(). I noticed it's not properly closed. The if condition match != 1 needs to be outside of the for loop.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong with your loop when you've only shown part of it.  Can you show us the rest?

Comment: Just uploaded the newest and somewhat more working code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is evaluating the `if(match != 1)` conditional each iteration through the `for` loop. What you are wanting to do is to iterate through the entire array first, then test your not-equal conditional at the end.

Move the `if(match != 1)` statement outside the for-loop.

edit: echo what other answer says about comparing doubles with tolerance levels.

Comment: Bryan, thanks for this. I really over looked my closed bracket. I now moved the if(match != 1) outside the for-loop, and it now is letting me search most of the numbers....but I had to remove "initalBalance.setText(" "); Now, when I search for 7623, it outputs the 1200.00 instead of the first 2000.00. I believe it has something to do when I removed that .setText command? ill throw my code at the top now

Answer (score 0):

It's generally bad practice to use == on doubles.  You want to check closeness within a tolerance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop your array backwards:

```
public static double findNextValue(double[][] arr, int value) {
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (Double.compare(arr[i][0], value) == 0)
            return arr[i][1];
    return Double.NaN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have to use a double[][] seems like you could use a Map and then no "search" needed do values.get(keyValue) // returns associated double.

Comment: He'd have duplicate keys in his current array structure... it would more likely need to return associated double[] with some other iteration through the value array.

Comment: missed there were dupes

Answer (score 0):

Add statement

```
break;
```

after

```
match = 1;
```